# When executing stored procedures in VB.NET/SQL, are we supposed to add "EXEC" or not?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures

I'm not sure what to believe anymore. When we are running our VB.NET `SqlCommand` off of stored procedures, do we add EXEC in our commands or not?!

I get an error:

> Could not find stored procedure 'EXEC uspGrabAutoByYMM'.

But then other people tell me you MUST put EXEC in there for it to run.

Here's my sample code:

```
Public Sub BindGridAutosYMM()
    Dim constring As String = "server=classified;database=classified"
    Using con As New SqlConnection(constring)
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("EXEC uspGrabAutoByYMM", con)
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Year", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Make", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Model", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            Using sda As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                Using dt As New DataTable()
                    sda.Fill(dt)
                    DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
    End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: No there is no need in this context to add EXEC

Comment: If you get an error when you add it, and you don't get an error when you omit it, then it sounds like you have your answer.  What "other people" tell you doesn't make much of a difference when you can demonstrate the code.

Comment: David. I definitely see your point. I DEFINITELY see your point. LOL. 

That's the same philosophy I had when I told people I wrote my SQL code inside VB with the @ symbols and people told me to store it in the SQL SSMS? Like It makes  no difference!! :D

Comment: Maybe those people didn't understand the context in which you were trying to execute a procedure. In this case, you're already giving `SqlCommand` a hint that it's a stored procedure, so it can take care of the `EXEC` part itself.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ, in this case I had to add it. Beforehand, I would run the program and it would say something along the lines of "We couldn't find the parameter @ Year so the program has aborted", ... , would the absence of that line be the reason why?

Comment: @Steve In what context can you tell me would there be a necessary time to write EXEC on that line?

Comment: I think he likely means by context that you are specifically telling the `SqlCommand` that it's `CommandType` is `SqlCommand.StoredProcedure`, so you don't need the "EXEC".

Comment: @RianBattle: Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure does it for you.

It will be helpful: [How to: Execute a Stored Procedure that Returns Rows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d7125bke.aspx)

See too:

> Using EXECUTE with Stored Procedures
>   You do not have to specify the EXECUTE keyword when you execute stored procedures when the statement is the first one in a batch.

[EXECUTE (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188332.aspx)

If you remove the "exec" and the problem persists, confirm that this procedure exists in your database.